# HA for the local Consul agent with Docker-Swarm

Tags: consul, docker-swarm

In my microservices system I plan to use docker swarm and Consul.
In order to ensure the high availability of Consul I’m going to build a cluster of 3 server agents (along with a client agent per node), but this doesn’t save me from local consul agent failure.

Am I missing something?
If not, how can I configure swarm to be aware of more than 1 consul agents?

Answer (score 0):

Consul is the only service discovery backend that don't support multiple endpoints while using swarm.

Both zookeeper and etcd support the etcd://10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5 format of providing multiple Ip's for the "cluster" of discovery back-ends while using Swarm.

To answer your question how you can configure Swarm to support more than 1 consul (server) - I don't have a definitive answer to it but can point you in a direction and something you can test ( no guarantees ) :

One suggestion worth testing (which is not recommended for production) is to use a Load Balancer that can pass your requests from the Swarm manager to one of the three consul servers.

So when starting the swarm managers you can point to consul://ip_of_loadbalancer:port

This will however cause the LB to be a bottleneck (if it goes down).

I have not tested the above and can't answer if it will work or not - it is merely a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @kamger, I'll tke it into consideration.